# Finding limits using l’Hôpital’s rule

Tags: limits

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}(e^{3x} - 5x)^{1/x}$

$\displaystyle\ln y=\frac{\ln(e^{3x} - 5x)}{x}$

Now applying l’Hôpital’s rule three times I can get the answer $3$.

That means,

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{3x} - 5x)^{1/x}=e^3$

But after finding this answer I understood that when I’m using l’Hôpital’s rule first time there isn't a $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form! There is an indeterminate form inside the $\ln$ which is $\ln (\infty-\infty)$ because $\lim_{x\to\infty}$

So which is the correct way to find the limits?

Comment: Some comments: 1) you can't publish questions with that format: at least use the dollars, and learn a bit of latex commands.
2) Explain better your doubts, people must understand what you don't understand to answer you.

Comment: 3) Make better use of parentheses: every line had an error with them.

Comment: F**k, if you don't want to improve your question take all the negative votes you deserve.

Comment: @Heshan Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, $e^{3x}-5x$ is an indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$, but this doesn't mean you can do nothing about it. Just consider
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{3x}-5x)=
\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{3x}\left(1-\frac{5x}{e^{3x}}\right)=\infty
$$
because the part in parentheses has limit $1$. Thus you indeed have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(e^{3x}-5x)}{x}
$$
in the indeterminate form $\infty/\infty$ and you can apply l’Hôpital:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(e^{3x}-5x)}{x}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3e^{3x}-5}{e^{3x}-5x}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{3x}\left(3-\dfrac{5}{e^{3x}}\right)}{e^{3x}\left(1-\dfrac{5x}{e^{3x}}\right)}=3
$$
(no need to go three times with l’Hôpital). The key fact used a few times here is that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t^k}{e^t}=0
$$
for every $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\exp(3x)-5x \to \infty$, we have $\ln (\exp(3x)-5x) \to \infty$, hence we do have the indeterminate form.

Remark:

Note the statement of L'hopital for $\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f_1(x)-f_2(x)}{g(x)}$ works  when $$\lim_{x \to c} [f_1(x) - f_2(x)]=\infty=\lim_{x \to c}g(x)$$

Comment: Use the dollars!!!

Comment: $[exp(3x) - 5\times x]$ is $(infini - infini)$ and not the just $infini$, so I sy that there is a indeterminate form inside the $\ln$, it is not th $\ln infin$

Comment: hmmm... what do you think is the limit of $x^2-5x$ as $x$ goes to infinity?

Answer (score 0):

Note that by standard limits

$$\frac{5x}{e^{3x}}\to 0$$

then

$$\frac{\ln(e^{3x} - 5x)}{x}=\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{5x}{e^{3x}}\right)+\ln e^{3x}}{x}=
\frac{5}{e^{3x}}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{5x}{e^{3x}}\right)}{\frac{5x}{e^{3x}}}
+\frac{\ln e^{3x}}{x}=\\=
\frac{5}{e^{3x}}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{5x}{e^{3x}}\right)}{\frac{5x}{e^{3x}}}
+3\to0\cdot1+ 3=3$$